# Can not install skype on ubuntu 12.04. How to solve this error?

Tags: skype

```
kithokit@09:39:03 ~ $ sudo apt-get install skype Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  skype : Depends: skype-bin E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. kithokit@09:39:13 ~ $ sudo apt-get install skype-bin Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  skype-bin:i386 : Depends: libasound2:i386 (>= 1.0.23) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libqt4-dbus:i386 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libqt4-network:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libqtgui4:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libqtwebkit4:i386 (>= 2.2~2011week36) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libxss1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libxv1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libssl1.0.0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: sni-qt:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. kithokit@09:39:18 ~ $
```

Comment: are you using 64bit or 32bit Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

Try via GUI Ubuntu Software Center? http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/skype

or download from Skype.com
http://download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb